# Sitecore Domain Access View

Tags: sitecore

Suppose that I created "newDomain" in Sitecore and there are many users such as `newDomain/author1`, `newDomain/author2`, `newDomain/developer1` and so on.

Also, there are other domains to make users separate in Sitecore, based on their domain.

That means `Domain1` group can only access `page1` item and `Domain2` group can only access `page2` item.

If I have only a few users in each domain, I can change the view access user by user. Otherwise, changing domain access view as group will be more easy if there are a number of users in each domain.

How can I implement this security setting? I have tried to find any function in Sitecore, but seems like there is not security setting for domain as a group.

Comment: As Martin mentioned, usually you would use a Sitecore Role for that kind of grouping. You would add users to a role, and assign access rights to the role instead of individual users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think domains are the appropriate way to differentiate your user access permissions in this case

Sitecore provides a security roles systems. Each user is  assigned to one or more roles, and roles can be granted various permissions for items. 
Roles exist within a domain.

Here's an introduction to roles:

https://www.sitecore.net/en-gb/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2013/01/sitecore-security-roles.aspx

The Sitecore security cookbook provides all you need to manage roles within Sitecore:

http://sdn.sitecore.net/reference/sitecore%206/security%20administrator%20cookbook.aspx